# Find largest product of negative numbers in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am taking a semi-advanced class in Java. I taught myself JavaScript as a hobby, so I'm not a real beginner, but I'm not very experienced when it comes to making algorithms. We have a homework problem to do. It goes along the lines of: Given *n* positive integers, where *n >= 5* find the largest product possible by picking two (not necessarily consecutive) numbers as factors.

For example, if the input is: `3 6 0 10 4`, the output should be `60`.

This seemed fairly easy. I just picked the largest two and multiplied them:

```
System.out.println("How many numbers will you give me?");
int n = sc.nextInt();
if (n < 5) throw new Error("n must be at least 5");
System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
int max1 = 0, max2 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int newInt = sc.nextInt();
    if (newInt > max1) {
        max2 = max1;
        max1 = newInt;
    } else if (newInt > max2) {
        max2 = newInt;
    }
}
System.out.println("The largest product is " + (max1 * max2));
```

This worked perfectly. Now, there was a "bonus" or extended problem after this one (optional). I decided to try it. The problem was similar: Given *n* (not necessarily positive) integers, find the largest product possible by picking two (not necessarily consecutive) numbers as factors. The program should run in a reasonable amount of time, given that *5 <= n <= 25*

The problem with the old program is that it would fail for inputs like `-6 -5 3 0 4`. It would ouput `12` when the correct answer was `30`. I decided to check for absolute values instead of the actual values, so negative numbers would be included. That code went something like:

```
System.out.println("How many numbers will you give me?");
int n = sc.nextInt();
if (n < 5) throw new Error("n must be at least 5");
System.out.println("Enter the numbers");
int max1 = 0, max2 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int newInt = sc.nextInt(), absValue = Math.abs(newInt);
    if (absValue > Math.abs(max1)) {
        max2 = max1;
        max1 = newInt;
    } else if (absValue > Math.abs(max2)) {
        max2 = newInt;
    }
}
System.out.println("The largest product is " + (max1 * max2));
```

This worked well with `-6 -5 3 0 4`, correctly giving `30` but failed for `-6 -3 1 5 4`. It gave an answer of `-30` which is obviously incorrect.

I tried a brute force solution, (checking every possible product) which worked very well for `n = 5` but requires `n!` iterations, which means that it takes a long time for `n = 25`.
I'm stumped on how to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Every possible combination of two numbers out of n is n choose 2, or n(n-1)/2 ~= n² which is far less than n! even for modest n, and a whole other league asymptotically.

Comment: @amit Yes, I'm sorry. It doesn't take `n!` it takes less than that, and it's possible that the question was even looking for that solution. However, it seemed like an easy enough problem that I should (could) do it in much less time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that checking the absolute value throws away the information that they may be negative. You need either two positive or two negative numbers.

The simplest way to achieve this will be to scan through, find the two smallest and the two largest numbers.

Multiple the two smallest. Multiply the two largest. Whichever of those is bigger is your result.

Comment: This is probably what they were looking for, not the brute force solution, even though it [brute force] works given their constraints

Answer (score 1):

Save in an array (`a`), sort the array, and then return `max(a[0]*a[1], a[a.length-1]*a[a.length-2])`.